# Regex causes StackOverflowError

Tags: java, regex, scala, parsing

I've got following regexp

```
(([^'])|(''))*
```

**which parse the literals well enough usually**

but with the following text (you can try it):

```
xxxxxxx_xxx_xxxxxxx=xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx`2[xxxxxx.xxxxxx,xxxxxx.xxxxxx]xxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxx_xxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=1455544499467&xxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxx_xxx_xx=xxxxxxx &xxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxx_xxx_xxxxxxxxx=xxxxxxx_701454xx-x23x-4x31-xx75-xxx185x3xx26&xxxxxx_xxxxxxxx_xxx_xxxxxxxxxx=xxxxx&xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxx_xxx_xxxxxxxxxx=xxxxxxx&xxxxxxxx_xxx_xx=xxxxxxx_2x542x7x-7x94-4867-8819-239x732xx3x1&xxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxx_xxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=xxxxx&xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxx_xxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx=xx-xx&xxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxx_xxx_xxxxxxxx=7&xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxx_xxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxx=xxx2012x2xx.xxx.xxx:82&xxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxx_xxx_xxxxxxx=11.0&xxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxx_xxx_xxxxxxx=xxxx&xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxx_xxx_xxxxxxxxxxxx=xxxxxxxxx&xx_xxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxx_xxx_xxxxxxx=xx 6.3&xxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxx_xxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=<xxxxxxx-xxxxx xxxxx="xxx">xxxxxx xxxxxx"></xxxxxxx><xxxxxxx-xxxx xxx-xxxxx="xx_xxxx" xxxxxxxx="xxxx" xxxx="xxxxxxxxxxx xxxx"><xxxx-xx-xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx="xxxx"><xxxxx>xxxxxxxxxx</xxxxx><xxxxx>xxxxx</xxxxx><xxxxx>xxx</xxxxx><xxxxx>xxxxxxxxx</xxxxx><xxxxx>xxxxxxx</xxxxx></xxxx-xx-xxxxxx></xxxxxxx-xxxx><xxxxxxx-xxxx xxx-xxxxx="xx_xxxxxxxx" xxxxxxxx="xxxxxxxx" xxxx="xx_xxxxxxxx"/><xxxxxxx-xxxx xxx-xxxxx="xx_xx_xxxxx" xxxxxxxx="xxxx" xxxx="xxxxxxx - xxxxxx xxxxxx?"><xxxx-xx-xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx="xxxxx"> 2</xxxxx></xxxx-xx-xxxxxx><xxxxx>xxxx</xxxxx><xxxxx>xxxxx</xxxxx></xxxx-xx-xxxxxx></xxxxxxx-xxxx><xxxxxxx-xxxx xxx-xxxxx="xx_xxxx_xxxx" xxxxxxxx="xxxx" xxxx="xx_xxxx_xxxx"></xxxxxxx><xxxxxxx-xxxx xxx-xxxxx="xx_xxxxxxx" xxxxxxxx="xxxxxx" xxxx="xx_xxxxxxx"></xxxxxxx><xxxxxxx-xxxx xxx-xxxxx="xx_xx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxx" xxxxxxxx="xxxx"xxxx="xxxxxxx - xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx"></xxxxxxx><xxxxxxx-xxxx xxx-xxxxx="xx_xxxxxx" xxxxxxxx="xxxx" xxxx="xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx">')
```

I get StackOverflowError:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4600)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4785)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4568)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3777)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
```

What could be the problem? 
Is it possible to have such exception because of too long length of the string (2030 symbols)?
Or do i have some special symbols here which causes this errors?

Any thoughts appreciated

Comment: @anubhava  it still has an exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you do not need the inner capturing groups. Repeated capturing groups only capture the last occurrence, so, they are useless in Java.

Next, you may [unroll](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop) this regex so that it matches linearly (without alternation that eats up a lot of resources):

```
[^']*(?:''[^']*)*
```

See the [updated regex](https://regex101.com/r/uD9nR9/1) demo.

**Pattern details**:

- `[^']*` - matches zero or more characters other than `'`
- `(?:''[^']*)*` - matches zero or more sequences of:

  - `''` - two single apostrophes
  - `[^']*` - zero or more  characters other than `'`

Comment: Thank you Wiktor. It helps me. Could you advice me how to learn regexp to know well  enough about efficient usage? any books, courses?

Comment: OReiley's Mastering Regular Expressions is considered the best textbook. Check SO regularly, there is one guy who is very proficient at regex performance here. Well, there are more but they do not show up often.